# Clicking link kills test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following command

```
selenium.click("link=Identify Awards");
```

opens a popup however the the test does not continue

I have placed

```
selenium.waitForPopUp(null, "1500");
selenium.windowFocus();
selenium.selectPopUp("Search -- Webpage Dialog");
```

After the click command to no avail
the link is to a goes to a java function.

I know that this command Clicks on a link, button, checkbox or radio button. If the click action causes a new page to load (like a link usually does), call
`waitForPageToLoad`.
I think that the `waitforPageToLoad` is not registering the popup loading

**Update**

I tried the following

```
selenium.fireEvent("link=Identify Awards", "onClick");
```

and got the following

The popup is on another domain could this be the cause?

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.openqa.selenium.ie.UnexpectedJavascriptExecutionException: Cannot execute script
System info: os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.5.0_12'
Driver info: driver.version: ie
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.ErrorHandler.verifyErrorCode(ErrorHandler.java:70)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.executeScript(InternetExplorerDriver.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.JavascriptLibrary.callEmbeddedSelenium(JavascriptLibrary.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.FireEvent.handleSeleneseCommand(FireEvent.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.FireEvent.handleSeleneseCommand(FireEvent.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.SeleneseCommand.apply(SeleneseCommand.java:33)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Timer.run(Timer.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.execute(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:277)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.doCommand(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:209)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.fireEvent(DefaultSelenium.java:201)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `selenium.selectWindow` to select popup and then use `selenium.selectWindow(null)` to select base window. You didn't describe as which kind of popup it is. Is a confirmation box or a frame or a model dialog or simply another window. selenium differ in treatment of all these

Answer (score 1):

I've found that on some occasions when triggering javascript in particular selenium's click function doesn't invoke the elements onClick command properly and this might be the problem you're encountering.

If so try using the following to explicitly fire the onClick event:

```
selenium.fire_event("link=Identify Awards", "onClick")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: just discovered that the popup that opens is a modal dialog